# Localhost refused to connect when trying to open web projects

Tags: reactjs, localhost

Im opening my project from visual studio code through this link: http://localhost:3000/ and everytime i open web projects it always says: This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. Try:  Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSEDHi. Please help me. Thank you.

I tried setting up the proxy server and nothing happend.